# How to assure the object of a nested private class in my arrayList is the one I want?

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4

This is my class, how I assure that the method insert() is working correctly?

```
public class HeapQueue<P extends Comparable<? super P>, V>
    implements PriorityQueue<P, V> {

private final ArrayList<Pair<P, V>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

private static class Pair<P extends Comparable<? super P>, V>
        implements Comparable<Pair<P, V>> {

    private final P priority;
    private final V value;

    public Pair(P priority, V value) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair<P, V> o) {
        return priority.compareTo(o.priority);
    }

}
```

I tried this test, but I can't assure the object Pair<> is correct.

```
    @Test
public void insertPrioritatAltaTest() {

    HeapQueue hq = new HeapQueue();
    Priority p1 = null;
    try {
        p1 = new Priority("Alta");
    } catch (InvalidInputError iie) {

    }
    int a = 1;

    hq.insert(p1, a);
    assertEquals(hq.size(),1);

}
```

I tried creating getters to extract the value of Pairs, but Netbeans warnered me that I was passing a private thing through a public API and moreover I wasn't obtaining it. 
I don't think declaring a public class Pair<> is the correct way to test this. Neither using the method extract() which I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often easiest to test your class by using it how a user would use it, and not worrying too much about the internal state.

I think you were on the right track with

> I tried creating getters to extract the value of Pairs

Although it sounds like you were getting an error because you were returning an instance of your private class `Pair<P,V>`. I'm not sure from your question exactly how the interface expects your class to behave, but it seems like you will want a `public V pop()` or similar function to be able to remove and return the next item in your `PriorityQueue`. Note that in this example, you would return a `V` type, **not** a `Pair`.

If that's the behavior you're looking for, your test would be similar to:

```
@Test
public void insertPrioritatAltaTest() {
    HeapQueue hq = new HeapQueue();
    hq.insert(new Priority("A"), 1);
    hq.insert(new Priority("C"), 2);
    hq.insert(new Priority("B"), 3);

    assertEquals(hq.pop(), 1);
    assertEquals(hq.pop(), 3);
    assertEquals(hq.pop(), 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I was getting so frustrated... This worked perfectly